# Can I call an event method of a parent from within an UpdatePanel on a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, updatepanel

I have the following scenario that I need to implement.

I have a `GridView` with a list of records.  When a user selects a record, a pop-over screen appears within the browser showing the contents of the record.  The contents are rendered from a `UserControl`, and within the `UserControl` there is an `UpdatePanel` that is used for loading/reloading data as it is manipulated and saved.

What I need to occur is that after each save on my `UserControl`, the `GridView` on the parent page needs to refresh as to reflect any changes on the record being shown in the pop-over editor control.

My plan is to setup an event on my `UserControl` that the parent page will subscribe too.  When a save operation is executed from within the `UserControl`, it will call the event, and the parent page should update itself.

However, since the `UserControl` operates within an `UpdatePanel`, and is only doing a partial-postback, I am suspect that my events will not work properly.

Should this work as I hope or will I need to find another way of telling my parent page to refresh the master `GridView` after a record is saved?

If I need to to call an update in a different manner, what is the best approach for this scenario?  I ask because I'd rather not build-out some complex saving/updating operation only to find out that I've made a few miss-assumptions and need to re-code the whole update and reload process.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that before I just don't remember exactly how as I haven't been working with Web Forms in a little while. You have the right idea. The event will get raised on the parent page but you will have to do another PostBack/Partial PostBack  afterwards to update the grid from the event handler on the parent. Also you will have to make sure the properties on the UpdatePanel have been set up right.

Another option is doing a full postback when you close the PopUp. If the popup is big enough that it prevents the user from seeing the grid it wont make a difference whether the record on the grid is updated when the Modal is closed rather than when the data is saved.